# Can't override parents javascript with my child themes javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

So i'm trying to tweak my wordpress site by tweaking the javascript needed to reduce the image sizes on the page. I have a js folder within my child themes folder structure that has one js file in it (which has the same name as the file it is meant to be overriding). Below is the code i'm using for the functions.php file which is meant to queue up the files. In my head it might have something to do with maybe how wordpress reads file, like maybe i have to do dequeue the parents javascript file or something?

Below is the functions.php file my child theme is using

```
  <?php
// Exit if accessed directly
if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

// BEGIN ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION
// AUTO GENERATED - Do not modify or remove comment markers above or below:

if ( !function_exists( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css' ) ):
    function chld_thm_cfg_parent_css() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'style.css', array( 'bootstrap','font-awesome' ) );
    }
endif;
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css', 10 );

// END ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION
```

Below is the part of the parents function.php file containing how it loads the scripts

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'simpleshift_public_scripts');

function simpleshift_public_scripts() {

    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.0.0',true);
        wp_enqueue_script('waypoints',get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js','','3.1.1',true);
        wp_enqueue_script('scrollreveal',get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/scrollReveal.min.js','','2.3.2',true);
        wp_enqueue_script('easing',get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery.easing.min.js','','1.3',true);
        wp_enqueue_script('waypoints-sticky',get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/sticky.min.js','','3.1.1',true);
        wp_enqueue_script('nicescroll',get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/nicescroll.min.js','','3.1.1',true);
        wp_enqueue_script('parallax',get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/parallax.min.js','','3.1.1',true);
        wp_enqueue_script('simpleshift_public',get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/public.js','','1.0.0',true);
        wp_enqueue_script('html5shiv',get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/html5shiv.js','','1.0.0',false);
        wp_script_add_data( 'html5shiv', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );
        wp_enqueue_script('respondjs',get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/respond.js','','1.0.0',false);
        wp_script_add_data( 'respondjs', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to dequeue scripts, look here : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26822/how-to-override-javascript-files-in-child-theme/26824#26824

Comment: in which folder did you add your own js file?

Comment: I added my own js folder within the child theme folder,

Comment: if the path of js file written right, then the the code I provided should do following: delete js file of your parent theme, add your own js file into your pages

Comment: I missed that your js file is in the child theme. instead of get_template_directory_uri() use get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). I refreshed code in the answer

Comment: Tried that and unfortunately, it's not working. Even went to test that changing the parents js file did what i expected it too and it did.

Comment: I uploaded the actual functions.php file my child theme is using. Maybe that'll help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first find your script in `.php` files. Depending on how its printing, you can use solution:

Its using some action, like

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', '/*some function*/' );
```

And in the function you'll find [wp_register_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/), or [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/):

```
wp_enqueue_script( $handle //you'll need handle name, ... )
```

After founding you need to add this code:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts', 20 );
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'simpleshift_public' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/public.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true);
}
```

Or the script in your theme can be printed using just `<script> html tag`(not recommended way ). In this case you need to comment or delete this tag from your parent theme, if you don't need it. After you just need to add your `js` file, using this code

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/public.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true);
}
```

if you has active child theme, then put the code at the end of `/your_child_theme_folder/functions.php` file. If not, then put it at the end of your parent theme `functions.php` file. Be sure, that there isn't `?>` closing tag. If its there, then just delete it and put the code instead of it.

Comment: I've found the following in the functions.php folder in the parent theme 
     wp_enqueue_script('simpleshift_public',get_template_directory_uri() . 
     '/assets/js/public.js','','1.0.0',true)

Where do i add the code you suggested?

Comment: if you has active child theme, then put the code at the end of /your_child_theme_folder/functions.php file

Comment: I'll include in the top post what my functions.php file looks like but it doesn#t seem to be overriding the parents js file still.

Comment: can you provide the all function with action you found in the parent theme?

Comment: Added to the original post

Comment: I worked it out, i was being an idiot and not uploading the right functions file to the right theme folder. Thankyou so much!!!!